# HTML5 input type date: how to make the date string

Tags: php, javascript, html

1i have been using html 5's input type="date" and found it very useful. i just wanna know if this is possible:

suppose i chose 1/01/2012 in the date picker

i want to save it on my database (mysql) but i want it to be like this " January 1,2012 "

are there ways to do it and how?

```
require_once "includes/database.php";

$title=$_POST['txtTitle'];
$old_date  = explode("/",$_POST['txtDate']);
$new_date = $old_date[1].' '.$old_date[0].','.$old_date[2];
$date=$new_date;
$from=$_POST['txtFrom'];
$to=$_POST['txtTo'];
$place=$_POST['txtPlace'];
$details=$_POST['txtDetails'];
$id=$_POST['txtEid'];   

        if($id==""){
            $sql = "INSERT INTO events (event_title,event_date,event_tfrom,event_tto,event_place,event_details) VALUES (:title,:date,:from,:to,:place,:details)";
            $qry = $db->prepare($sql);
            $qry->execute(array(':title'=>$title,':date'=>$date,':from'=>$from,':to'=>$to,':place'=>$place,':details'=>$details));
        }else{
        $sql = "UPDATE events SET event_title=?, event_date=?, event_tfrom=?, event_tto=?, event_place=?, event_details=? WHERE event_id=?";
            $qry = $db->prepare($sql);
            $qry->execute(array($title,$date,$from,$to,$place,$details,$id));
        }

    echo "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Successfully Saved!')</script>";
    echo "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>window.open('cms_events.php','_self')</script>";
```

Comment: Why not save it in the date's default format (YYYY-MM-DD) and then alter the date when it is read from the database? The date will be in a generic mSQL DATE format and thus can have its format easily altered throughout you application.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/kj3c1.png?1 i want to make it like what in that picture shows. but all the date were coming from my database and the date saves in int values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using javascript you can do something like this

```
    <button onclick = "getDate()">click for date</button>
    <script>
    function getDate(){
       var monthsOfYear = new Array("January", "February", "March", 
"April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", 
"October", "November", "December");

   var d = new Date();
   var currdate = d.getDate();
   var currmonth = d.getMonth();
   var curryear = d.getFullYear();

   alert(monthsOfYear[currmonth] + " "+currdate+","+curryear);
}
```

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using some php functions explode.

```
$old_date  = explode("-",$_POST['date']);

$new_date = $old_date[2].' '.$old_date[1].','.$old_date[0];

echo $new_date;
```

You will get in this format January 1,2012

Comment: I don't think you will get January. You will get 1 instead.

Comment: $old_date  = explode("/",$_POST['txtDate']);
$new_date = $old_date[1].' '.$old_date[0].','.$old_date[1];
$date=$new_date;

i am now getting an error:
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\pcf\saveevent.php on line 6

Comment: @Hussain Yes you wont because you have to change the month from 'm' to 'M' , so that January is displayed instead 01, February displayed instead of 02 ..etc

Comment: @JB De Asis can you display your complete code so that i can debug it??

Comment: Dude Just check your code and also whether $_POST['txtDate'] is working for you....The code i hav written is working perfectly for me though

Comment: $new_date = $old_date[Y].' '.$old_date[m].','.$old_date[D];

Comment: Just change it to                                                               $new_date = $old_date[1].' '.$old_date[0].','.$old_date[2];

Comment: it says Notice: Undefined offset: 1

Comment: better send me your complete code, you  might hav missed something

Comment: ok JB De Asis just try to print the value of echo $_POST['txtDate'];  and tell me what exactly is stored in txtDate

Comment: Ok so i found out what the problem is , i am changing my code according to your requirements. So just execute and see nw

Comment: @JB De Asis are you using the current date as an input for txtDate ??

Comment: Ok for the January to appear you must make changes in your datepicker plugin

Answer (score 0):

This wil work perfectly fine for your code, check it..

```
$old_date  = explode("-",$date);



$months = array('January'=>"01",'February'=> "02", 'March'=>"03",'April'=>"04",  'May'=>"05", 'June'=>"06", 'July'=>"07", 'August'=>"08",'September'=> "09",'October'=>"10", 'November'=>"11", 'December'=>"12");


$nw_month = array_search($old_date[1],$months);


$new_date = $old_date[2].' '.$nw_month.','.$old_date[0];

echo $new_date;
```

Comment: @JB De Asis try the above code, you wil get your desired result